# Python. Ошибка при запуске приложения python на Windows, скомпилированного на Nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.10

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда тестировал приложение Python в скомпилированном виде при помощи модуля Nuitka на виртуальной машине Windows 8.1 и Windows 10.

При открытии приложения появлялось диалоговое окно с ошибкой : Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует python310.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу.

Такая же ошибка появлялась и после переустановки программы. Возможно ли внести какие-либо коррективы в код, чтобы программа не выдавала ошибки?

Также хотелось бы отметить, что такая ошибка не возникает, если программа будет скомпилирована при помощи PyInstaller. Программа была скомпилирована при помощи Nuitka. Компилировал на этом модуле, потому что он оптимизирует программу Python.

Comment: Nuitka зависима от python. Пытаться сделать ее самостоятельной - сложно. Для создания независимых exe файлов используйте pyinstaller.  Nuitka призвана просто сделать ваш код быстрее.

Comment: А можно сделать быстрый код без зависмостей на Nuitka?

Comment: Раньше я тоже пытался решить туже задачу что и вы.  И потратил кучу времени на её решение. Но мне так это и не удалось. Возможно у вас это выйдет. Для начала попробуйте это: https://coderoad.ru/49831163/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-Python-3-6-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-exe-%D1%81-Nuitka-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Windows-10

Comment: быстрый способ, установите pyinstaller и попробуйте это `pyinstaller --onefile program.py`